# R Sub function: pull everything after second number

Tags: r, regex

Trying to figure out how to pull everything after the second number using the sub function in R. I understand the basics with the lazy and greedy matching, but how do I take it one step further and pull everything after the second number?

```
str <- 'john02imga-04'
```

#lazy: pulls everything after first number

```
sub(".*?[0-9]", "", str)
```

#output: "2imga-04

#greedy: pulls everything after last number

```
sub(".*[0-9]", "", str)
```

#output: ""

#desired output: "imga-04"

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, it has, I just couldnt accept both solutions as the answer :(

Comment: I see, so the other answer worked best for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a capture group for the second part and use that in the replacement

```
^\D+\d+(\D+\d+)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\D+\d+` Match 1+ non digits, then 1+ digits
- `(\D+\d+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ non digits and match 1+ digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q17AkC/1) | [R demo](https://ideone.com/yuCQSW)

```
str <- 'john02imga-04'
sub("^\\D+\\d+(\\D+\\d+)", "\\1", str)
```

Output

```
[1] "imga-04"
```

If you want to remove all after the second number:

```
^\D+\d+(\D+\d+).*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PFQYso/1)

---

As an alternative getting a match only using `perl=T` for using PCRE and `\K` to clear the match buffer:

```
str <- 'john02imga-04'
regmatches(str, regexpr("^\\D+\\d+\\K\\D+\\d+", str, perl = T))
```

Output

```
[1] "imga-04"
```

See an [R demo](https://ideone.com/FtNZwV)

Comment: Thank you for this response and sharing the Regex demo. I will definitely work on learning this

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```r
sub("\\D*[0-9]+", "", str)
## Or,
## sub("\\D*\\d+", "", str)
## => [1] "imga-04"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YJECit/1). Also, see [**the R demo online**](https://ideone.com/Zv5EFz).

`sub` will find and replace the first occurrence of

- `\D*` (=`[^0-9]`) - any zero or more non-digit chars
- `[0-9]+` (=`\d+`) - one or more digits.

**Alternative ways**

Match one or more letters, `-`, one or more digits at the end of the string:

```r
> regmatches(str, regexpr("[[:alpha:]]+-\\d+$", str))
[1] "imga-04"

> library(stringr)
> str_extract(str, "\\p{L}+-\\d+$")
[1] "imga-04"
```